# Symfony4 API Controller Parent

Tags: api, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony4

I realize an application under Symfony4 for the creation of an API. I am looking to create a parent controller for the CRUD that will be extended on my other controllers to avoid copying all the CRUD code. Do you have an example please? Here is what I already did on a controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Exception\ResourceValidationException;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcherInterface;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Security;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use App\Representation\Articles;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

class ArticleController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get(
     *     path="/api/articles/{id}",
     *     name="app_article_show",
     *     requirements={"id"="\d+"}
     * )
     * @Rest\View()
     *
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Return article."
     * )
     * @SWG\Tag(name="Article")
     * @Security(name="Bearer")
     */
    public function showAction(Article $article)
    {
        return $article;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Post(
     *     path = "/api/articles",
     *     name= "app_article_create",
     *  )
     * @Rest\View(StatusCode= 201)
     * @ParamConverter(
     *     "article", converter="fos_rest.request_body",
     *     options={
                "validator"={ "groups"="Create"}
     *     }
     * )
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Create article"
     * )
     * @SWG\Tag(name="Article")
     * @Security(name="Bearer")
     */
    public function createAction(Article $article, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
    {
        if (count($violations)) {
            $message = 'The JSON sent contain invalid data: ';
            foreach ($violations as $violation) {
                $message .= sprintf(
                    "Field %s: %s",
                    $violation->getPropertyPath(),
                    $violation->getMessage()
                );
            }
            throw new ResourceValidationException($message);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->view(
            $article,
            Response::HTTP_CREATED,
            [
                'Location' => $this->generateUrl('app_article_create', ['id', $article->getId()], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL)
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Get(
     *     path="/api/articles",
     *     name="app_article_list"
     * )
     * @Rest\QueryParam(
     *     name="keyword",
     *     requirements="[a-zA-Z0-9]",
     *     nullable=true,
     *     description="The keyword to search for."
     * )
     * @Rest\QueryParam(
     *     name="order",
     *     requirements="asc|desc",
     *     default="asc",
     *     description="Sort order (asc or desc)"
     * )
     * @Rest\QueryParam(
     *     name="limit",
     *     requirements="\d+",
     *     default="16",
     *     description="Max number of movies per page."
     * )
     * @Rest\QueryParam(
     *     name="offset",
     *     requirements="\d+",
     *     default="1",
     *     description="The pagination offset"
     * )
     * @Rest\View()
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="List all articles."
     * )
     * @SWG\Tag(name="Article")
     * @Security(name="Bearer")
     */
    public function listAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
        $pager = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->search(
            $paramFetcher->get('keyword'),
            $paramFetcher->get('order'),
            $paramFetcher->get('limit'),
            $paramFetcher->get('offset')
        );

        return new Articles($pager);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think there's a lot wrong with that. Too many things in annotations. You also shouldn't put that logic for getting things from database in controllers! You should be a Dependency Injection instead of $this->getDoctrine() which is just a service locator pattern. Why would you like to extend this controller? This is specific for articles.

I would rewrite the whole thing without FosRestBundle to learn how it really works, however try to do more research about API designs in symfony and about symfony in general.

Answer (score 0):

Before Symfony 4, you could use [Doctrine CRUD controller generation feature](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html). Just take a look if you just want an example.

Now you can use [Symfony Maker Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html)as a new alternative. They say [here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/releases/tag/v1.2.0) that there is a new command **make:crud** and they improved the existing **make:form**